# Mapbox GL JS How to handle multiple map styles/sprites at the same time in a map?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

We are using mapbox-gl-js for a mapping web app, we have several custom styles (made with mapbox studio) that we use like layers that we render above our base layers, a base layer can be the mapbox satellite layer, and a custom layer a style that shows information about soils (for example).

I want to know if someone has faced this situation, we've find some workarounds to handle our needs, but isn't really easy and takes time each time we modify a custom style.

Here is a list of issues that we have faced and resolved:

- Can't load more that one style per map, so there is no easy way to
  load all the custom styles that we have at the same time, and we need to
  do it.

  In order to show each style in the map, we add each layer in the
  style to the map individually, we inspect the layers inside the style
  object and iterate over it adding each layer.
- Can't load more than one sprite per map, each style has it's own
  sprite, with the resources it needs, for example a svg for a fill
  pattern. If we load the sprite for one style, the other styles won't
  show correctly, because they also have layers that needs svgs from
  their sprites.

  To solve this we have a style that contains the svgs of all the other
  styles, so we can load the sprite of this style and all the other
  styles are displayed correctly. This works, but the sprite has a
  limit of 500 icons (more or less depending on the size of your icons), and we will reach that limit eventually, that's
  one of our biggest concerns.

Comment: Interesting problem. Another possible workaround would be to request the other styles as raster tiles.

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ Yeah, it's a possible solution, but we want vectorial layers for their performance, features, style, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing the official supported way to do this is to copy your style rules from your studio style layer, and then load the tilesets for those studio styles individually, and locally apply your style rules to each layer